# Azure ADB2C Passwordless Numeric keyboard while entering Phone number

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-ad-b2c, serverless

I am using the Azure ADB2C passwordless authentication method. When I open the app on the mobile, it shows a generic keyboard rather than the Numeric keyboard, which is kind of annoying. Any help would be highly appreciated. [![enter image description here.

[image]

This should be numeric keyboard poping up instead of alphanumeric keyboard.

Comment: I don't think it can be done by XML, you must create a custom UI, I guess.

Comment: you mentioned a lot of things: passwordless, phone number and password (wasn't it passwordless??). I didn't get what's your scenario

Comment: We are using passwordless authentication that uses OTP-based authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Set the [claimType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claimsschema#claimtype) to `phoneNumber`. This should set the correct HTML tag for mobile phones to show the numeric pad.